# R, Leaflet - Radius Overlapping Polygon

Tags: r, leaflet, polygon, overlap

I have an app in R where I would like to know if a radius that is X meters from a centroid overlaps a particular polygon.  So, the idea is that if I click on the polygon, the app will show which objects have a radius that overlaps the polygon:
[image]

Any ideas would be extremely helpful.  I feel like I need to compare coordinates from a shape file that I bring in to the centroid plus the radius.  I thought maybe the intersect method from the raster library would do the trick, however, when I look at the documentation, I feel like I don't know how to get it to read the shape file or the centroid plus radius.

My code is listed below:

```
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)

zone_file <- readOGR("ZONE_ARC_MAP_OBJECT/Shape/ZoneRTest.shp", layer = "ZoneRTest")
mpo_overall <- read.csv("MPOEVI_OVERALL_TEST.csv")
mpo_zip <- read.csv("MPOEVI_ZIP_TEST.csv")
    leaflet(zone_file) %>%
      addTiles() %>% 
      addCircles(lng = mpo_overall$LONGITUDE, lat = mpo_overall$LATITUDE, radius = mpo_overall$RADIUS,
             popup = paste(mpo_overall$TOTAL_ORDERS)) %>%
      addPolygons(data = zone_file, fill = TRUE, stroke = TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.1,
              color = ifelse(zone_file$ZONEONTIME >=.92, 'green', 
                             ifelse(zone_file$ZONEONTIME >=.82, 'orange', 'red')),
              smoothFactor = 0.9,
              #stroke = TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.2, smoothFactor = 0.5,
              popup = paste("Zone: ", zone_file$OBJECTID, "<br>",
                            "Total Orders: ", zone_file$ZONETOTALO, "<br>",
                            "On-Time%: ", zone_file$ZONEONTIME, "<br>",
                            "Revenue: ", zone_file$ZONEREVENU))
```

Comment: Have a look at the **rgeos** package, and its `gIntersects()` function in particular.